# I am trying to check for expired token for ebay sdk with GetClientAlertsAuthTokenCall

Tags: java, ebay-api

I need to set up a routine to check the token when using eBay sdk. From what I can see I need to use GetClientAlertsAuthTokenCall and execute it. I am not sure how I execute it. Or is there a better way to check for a token about to expire? Here is what I have so far for the check.

```
 public boolean isTokenExpiring() {
    try {
        GetClientAlertsAuthTokenCall tokenCall = new GetClientAlertsAuthTokenCall(getApiContext());
        tokenCall.execute(null);
        Calendar expireCalendar=tokenCall.getReturnedHardExpirationTime();
        Calendar currentCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Here is the code that I used. Please note that I save the tokens so I call a different method to get it.

```
    public boolean isTokenExpiring() {
    try {
        ApiContext apiContext = new ApiContext();

        //set Api Token to access eBay Api Server
        ApiCredential cred = apiContext.getApiCredential();
        ApiAccount account = new ApiAccount();
        account.setApplication(APP_ID);
        account.setCertificate(CERT_ID);
        account.setDeveloper(DEV_ID);
        cred.setApiAccount(account);
        cred.seteBayToken(getLogInToken());
        apiContext.setApiServerUrl(SOAP_URL);
        apiContext.setApiCredential(cred);

        GetTokenStatusCall call = new GetTokenStatusCall(apiContext);

        TokenStatusType status = call.getTokenStatus();
        Calendar expCalendar = status.getExpirationTime();
        Calendar cur = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        if (expCalendar.getTimeInMillis() < cur.getTimeInMillis()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}
```